# How can you create variable number of jpanels within a jframe or jpanel based on number of entries

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

[Sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEJWK.png)

I am attempting to build a GUI with JPanels which can display multiple projects, with multiple tasks displayed inside each table (see image). My team is using a database to hold all the project/task data. The project panels are all within a scroll frame, and each project panel can scroll as well.

I am trying to learn how to display the same number of projects in my frame that are in my database. There are not fixed numbers of projects or tasks, so I want to add a panel when it corresponds to an entry in the database. How can I only create the number of panels necessary, making the page dynamic?

Any information that can point out what I should be studying to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're trying to do, the feat itself would not require an incredibly complex solution.

Ideally, you should create a structure or an object which contains all relevant information for your specific `JPanel`. From this, the objects can be stored within an `ArrayList`.

Looping for the number of objects present within the `ArrayList`, you can then simply create a new instance of your required `JPanel` using the information from within said object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, that is what I was imagining, so I'm glad to hear it is feasible. What method do I use then to create the correct orientation/layout. So each new project is placed to the right of the previous, each new task below its predecessor?